# Project builds a JAR; I want to cause that JAR to be in ~/.m2/repository so I can consume it from other projects; how is this done?

Tags: java, maven

The source code to the resulting JAR is in my project, *abc*.

The packaging of my *pom.xml* is "jar".

When I have done `mvn package` I would like to see my JAR on the path *~/.m2/repository/com/acme/abc/abc/1.0.0/abc-1.0.0.jar* (with all the other files there .md5, .sha1, .pom, etc.) so that I can pick it up from any other project. (This is in lieu of putting my JAR into Maven Central or Nexus, etc.)

I have been exploring *maven-install-plugin* with *install-jar-lib*, *install-file*, etc., different configuration, but to no avail.

When I build (`mvn package`), I do not see *~/.m2/repository/com/acme/abc...* at all yet under my local *target* directory, I see *abc-1.0.0.jar*. However, it appears that `mvn install` does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to run the command `mvn install` to get your artifact into your maven local repository.